# Finding compound words with Trie in python

Tags: algorithms, strings

So I have a trie in python but its not leading to the runtime complexity I want from my algorithm to find compound words. I was originally trying to use this algorithm but had no luck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291734/finding-dictionary-words

So the words are

```
['bye','byeen','s','byeens']
# My Trie (*) denotes a word ending
# b - y - e* - e - n* - s* , s*
```

My algorithm checks the word byeens in the trie and if it exists and then checks if all the individual words exist

So it checks if

```
'Bye' exists, 'en' exists, and 's' exists. When checking if 'Byeens' is a compound word
```

While this works for most situations. It obviously doesnt work for this one. The way I found to remedy this is when checking the trie for byeens it constructs two different paths to check if either exist

```
['bye','en','s'] # doesnt exist
['byeens','s'] # does exist
```

However, what if the trie is composed of all a's? like this for example

```
a*-a*-a*-a*-a*
```

this gets big... really fast. To the order of 2^m-1 where m is the length of the word I believe.

Anyone found a better way to do this?

Comment: Python is offtopic here. What is the problem you are trying to solve? What is the (idea of) your algorithm?

Comment: I can't understand the idea behind your algorithm.  Can you give pseudocode describing your data structure & algorithm?  Can you draw a picture to show the structure of your trie?  I don't know what `b - y - e* - e - n* - s* , s*` or `a*-a*-a*-a*-a*` means.  Aside from your current approach, what problem exactly are you trying to solve?  Can you give a self-contained specification of the problem, explained independently of your approach?